# How to Add Sub Items to a MenuStrip's ToolStripMenuItem in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

I have added a `menustrip1` into my windows form and I statically added one `toolstripmenuitem` (WindowstoolStripmenuItem) to that `menustrip1`.
And I have created a toolstripmenuitem dynamically. I want to add this dynamic toolstripmenuitem to the static menustripitem(WindowstoolStripmenuItem) which is created statically on design time.

```
ToolStripMenuItem itm = new ToolStripMenuItem();
itm.Name = "fm1";
itm.Text = "Form1";
```

How can I add this subitem to the static menustrip's Windows item.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add a `ToolStripMenuItem` to another `ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems` collection.

If you don't have a reference to your ToolStripMenuItem, you can get one by key (Name Property) or Index

```
var itm = menustrip1.Items["Text"];
var itm = menustrip1.Items[0];
```

Here is the code

```
var menustrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
var item = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
{
    Name = "Test",
    Text = "Test" 
};
var item2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
{
    Name = "Test",
    Text = "Test"
};
item.DropDownItems.Add(item2);
menustrip1.Items.Add(item);
```