# winform-how to print multiple table tag in excel with C#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I have Data print in `excel` 2 table tag used and generate `excel` visible but my error is a not print two table only one table print 
I am create simple project in `c#` `page_Load` then Open `Excel` and Display `two table` in `excel file` but some error will be generate only one table display

My Code

```
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb1 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook xlWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        sb.Append("<html>");
        sb.Append("<head></head>");
        sb.Append("<body>");
        sb.Append("<table border=1>");
        sb.Append("<tr style=height:30px;>");
        sb.Append("<td style='min-width:50px;text-align:center;font-size:20px;background-color:#c0c0c0;' colspan=6>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>Meru Malakiya</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("</tr>");
        sb.Append("<tr style='height:30px;'>");
        sb.Append("<td style='min-width:50px;text-align:center'>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>No.</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style=min-width:50px;text-align:center>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>D 3</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='text-align:center;font-size:14px;background-color:#c0c0c0;min-width:50px' colspan='2'>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>DEAF-Claim Principal</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='text-align:center;font-size:14px;background-color:#c0c0c0;min-width:50px'>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>G.L.</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='text-align:center;font-size:14px;min-width:50px'>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>Head Office</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("</tr>");


        sb.Append("</table></body></html>");



        sb1.Append("<html>");
        sb1.Append("<head></head>");
        sb1.Append("<body>");
        sb1.Append("<table border=1>");
        sb1.Append("<tr style=height:30px;>");
        sb1.Append("<td style='min-width:50px;text-align:center;font-size:20px;background-color:#c0c0c0;' colspan=6>");
        sb1.Append("<nobr><b>Sanjay Malakiya</b></nobr>");
        sb1.Append("</td>");
        sb1.Append("</tr>");
        sb1.Append("<tr style='height:30px;'>");
        sb1.Append("<td style='min-width:50px;text-align:center'>");
        sb1.Append("<nobr><b>No.</b></nobr>");
        sb1.Append("</td>");
        sb1.Append("<td style=min-width:50px;text-align:center>");
        sb1.Append("<nobr><b>D 3</b></nobr>");
        sb1.Append("</td>");
        sb1.Append("<td style='text-align:center;font-size:14px;background-color:#c0c0c0;min-width:50px' colspan='2'>");
        sb1.Append("<nobr><b>DEAF-Claim Principal</b></nobr>");
        sb1.Append("</td>");
        sb1.Append("<td style='text-align:center;font-size:14px;background-color:#c0c0c0;min-width:50px'>");
        sb1.Append("<nobr><b>G.L.</b></nobr>");
        sb1.Append("</td>");
        sb1.Append("<td style='text-align:center;font-size:14px;min-width:50px'>");
        sb1.Append("<nobr><b>Head Office</b></nobr>");
        sb1.Append("</td>");
        sb1.Append("</tr>");


        sb1.Append("</table></body></html>");
        String Todaysdate1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\" + Todaysdate1))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\" + Todaysdate1);
        }
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\" + Todaysdate1 + "\\Print Voucher.XLS"))
        {
           // file1.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            file1.WriteLine(sb1.ToString());
        }
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\" + Todaysdate1 + "\\Print Voucher.XLS"))
        {
            file.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

        }
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook xlWorkBook1 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        xlWorkBook1 = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\" + Todaysdate1 + "\\Print Voucher.XLS", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet Wt1 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook1.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Visible = true;

    }
```

[image: Not print two table only show one table]

any idea for this question

regard Sanjay malakiya

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-use-tooltips-in-toolstrip-controls

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721627/how-to-add-sub-items-to-a-menustrips-toolstripmenuitem-in-c-sharp

Comment: @MichaelRandall not add i want create run-time click event

Comment: @T.S. Not show Data but I want create run-time Click Event menutrip

Comment: It would be much cleaner using a [Runtime T4 Template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39713817/3110834).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 file only one time using Html Tag and multiple time using Table tag

My Code :-

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb1 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook xlWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        sb.Append("<html>");
        sb.Append("<head></head>");
        sb.Append("<body>");
        sb.Append("<table border=1>");
        sb.Append("<tr style=height:30px;>");
        sb.Append("<td style='min-width:50px;text-align:center;font-size:20px;background-color:#c0c0c0;' colspan=6>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>Meru Malakiya</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("</tr>");
        sb.Append("<tr style='height:30px;'>");
        sb.Append("<td style='min-width:50px;text-align:center'>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>No.</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style=min-width:50px;text-align:center>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>D 3</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='text-align:center;font-size:14px;background-color:#c0c0c0;min-width:50px' colspan='2'>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>DEAF-Claim Principal</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='text-align:center;font-size:14px;background-color:#c0c0c0;min-width:50px'>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>G.L.</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='text-align:center;font-size:14px;min-width:50px'>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>Head Office</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("</tr>");
        sb.Append("</table>");

        sb.Append("<br/>");
        sb.Append("<br/>");
        sb.Append("<br/>");
        sb.Append("<br/>");
        sb.Append("<br/>");
        sb.Append("<br/>");
        sb.Append("<br/>");
        sb.Append("<br/>");
        sb.Append("<br/>");
        sb.Append("<br/>");
        sb.Append("<br/>");




        sb.Append("<table border=1>");
        sb.Append("<tr style=height:30px;>");
        sb.Append("<td style='min-width:50px;text-align:center;font-size:20px;background-color:#c0c0c0;' colspan=6>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>Sanjay Malakiya</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("</tr>");
        sb.Append("<tr style='height:30px;'>");
        sb.Append("<td style='min-width:50px;text-align:center'>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>No.</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style=min-width:50px;text-align:center>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>D 3</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='text-align:center;font-size:14px;background-color:#c0c0c0;min-width:50px' colspan='2'>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>DEAF-Claim Principal</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='text-align:center;font-size:14px;background-color:#c0c0c0;min-width:50px'>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>G.L.</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("<td style='text-align:center;font-size:14px;min-width:50px'>");
        sb.Append("<nobr><b>Head Office</b></nobr>");
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("</tr>");

       // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PrintExcel", spPrint.ToString());
        sb1.Append("</table></body></html>");
        String Todaysdate1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\" + Todaysdate1))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\" + Todaysdate1);
        }
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\" + Todaysdate1 + "\\Print Voucher.XLS"))
        {
            file1.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
           // file1.WriteLine(sb1.ToString());
        }

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook xlWorkBook1 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        xlWorkBook1 = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\" + Todaysdate1 + "\\Print Voucher.XLS", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet Wt1 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook1.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Visible = true;

    }
```

Output

[image: Only One Time Using <code>Sb.Append("<html>")</code> Tag in Your <code>C#</code> Form]